# proof of the minimum number of nodes in an avl tree

Tags: nodes, min, avl-tree

How do i prove that the minimum number of nodes in an avl tree of height *h* is
**(5+2*5^(1/2))*((((1+5^(1/2))/2)^h) + (5-2*5^(1/2))*((((1-5^(1/2))/2)^h)-1**?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that a root node at height h has two subtrees. The one of these two subtrees height must be h-1. The structure of an AVL tree forces the other subtree to have height at least h-2. Thus the one subtree has the minimum possible number of nodes an the other has the maximum possible number of nodes.
So we get the following recursive rules : n(0) = 1, n(1) = 2, n(h) = n(h-1)+n(h-2)+1 where n(h) is the minimum number of nodes at height = h.

This recurrence is very close to the Fibonacci sequence. Calculating the exact formula of Fibonacci sequence we get F(n) = (φ^n - hat(φ)^n)/sqrt(5) where φ = (1+sqrt(5))/2 and hat(φ) = (1-sqrt(5))/2.

This should give some idea how to proceed.
I think that doing some math here will lead you to the answer.